# Finding a list of files by name given a list of keywords and finding the list of keywords that were not found

Tags: bash, unix, find

The problem: I have a list of keywords like this in file call keywords.txt

```
141367
141374
141376
141368
```

and I need to use it to search a large complex folder for any file with any of the keywords in its name. I need a report of two different lists.

1. The list of files found that contains any of the keywords in its name.
2. The list of keywords that were never found in any file name.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

untested

```
files=$(find folder_name -type f | fgrep -f keywords.txt)

not_found=$(comm -23 <(sort keywords.txt) <(fgrep -f keywords.txt <<< "$files" | sort)
```

Comment: The 'files' query searches the content of the file, how would you just search the name of the file?

Comment: Woops, I take that back. But it looks like the 'files' query just listed all the files in the directory, it didn't filter it based on the keywords.txt file.

Comment: I take that back too. First query worked great. Second one isn't working for me. The 'fgrep -f keywords.txt <<< "$files" | sort' resulted in a list of file names and not a list of keywords.

Comment: this worked: 'comm -23 <(sort keywords.txt) <(fgrep -of keywords.txt <<< "$files" | sort | uniq)' thank you for your help.

Comment: You could use `sort -u` to save one process.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something in `bash` (ver4+)

```
#!/bin/bash

filecontent=($(<file))
shopt -s globstar
for file in **
do
    found="0"
    for word in ${filecontent[@]}
    do
       case "${file##*/}" in
         *"$word"* )
            echo "file found: $file with keyword: $w"
            found="1"
            ;;
       esac
    done
    case "$found" in
        "0") echo "No keyword file: $file";;
    esac
done
```